# R Shiny How to build a dynamic conditionalPanel

Tags: r, shiny

Examples

```
sidebarPanel(
   selectInput(
      "plotType", "Plot Type",
      c(Scatter = "scatter",
        Histogram = "hist")),

   # Only show this panel if the plot type is a histogram
   conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.plotType == 'hist'",
      selectInput(
         "breaks", "Breaks",
         c("Sturges",
           "Scott",
           "Freedman-Diaconis",
           "[Custom]" = "custom")),

      # Only show this panel if Custom is selected
      conditionalPanel(
         condition = "input.breaks == 'custom'",
         sliderInput("breakCount", "Break Count", min=1, max=1000, value=10)
      )
   )
)
```

Hi everyone. This is the example of conditionalPanel() typing ?

I would like to know how can I use the output of the selectInput inside conditionalPanel().

For example I want a program like this:

```
 condition = "input.plotType == 'input$plotType'",
      selectInput( -- here -- depends on the input)
```

My input is like this:

```
a a1
a a2
a a3
b b1
b b2
c c1
c c2
d d1
d d2 
d d3
```

I would like to choose between a,b,c and d and after I would like to choose between a1,a2,a3 if i chosed a, b1 and b2 if I chosed b, ecc.

I could do it by hand but I have a lot of variables and a dynamic sub-distribution.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look in renderUI().

ui side:

```
conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.plotType == 'hist'",
      uiOutput("fromServer")
),
```

server side:

```
output$fromServer <- renderUI({
   ## Now you can use inputs like input$plotType to build your selectInput
   selectInput(
         "breaks", "Breaks",
         c("Sturges",
           "Scott",
           "Freedman-Diaconis",
           "[Custom]" = "custom"
    )
})
```